# Clonando select dentro de un div

Tags: php, jquery, html5, bootstrap-4

hola tengo el siguiente código de un formulario de la aplicacion que estoy desarrollando

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/fontawesome/css/all.css">
        <script src="CSS/fontawesome/js/all.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Acuerdos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" >
            
            <fieldset>
                <form id="archivo">
                    <legend> Captura de Acuerdo </legend>
                    <div class="alert alert-info" style="width: 100%;">
                        <strong>Los campos obligatorios estan marcados con * </strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                            <input  id="time" name="time" class="form-control" type="number" lang="en"   value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row" id="actividades">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <label for="inputState" id="nombre"><strong>* </strong>A. Global:</label>
                            <select id="ActvG" class="form-control" name="ActvG" onchange=""  >
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <label for="inputState" id="nombre">A. General:</label>
                            <select id="ActvP" class="form-control" name="ActvP" onchange="" >
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <label for="inputState" id="nombre">A. Particular:</label>
                            <select id="SubAct" class="form-control" name="SubAct" onchange="">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                            <label for="inputState" id="nombre">SubActividad:</label>
                            <select id="SubbAct" class="form-control" name="SubbAct" >
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="font-size: 0.6rem;line-height: 0.9;" onclick="">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nuevaactividad">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="JS/acciones.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/Alta_Archivo.js"></script>
</html>
```

lo que quiero lograr es que cada vez que le den click al botón de mas el div con el id de actividades se clone con sus select que tiene adentro y en el imput de asta arriba aumente su valor para poder enviar ese valor a mi controlador y que el sistema haga los insert necesarios en mi base de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tengo una respuesta para tu problema **(MODIFICADO + BOTON ELIMINAR)** , hice un codigo en **JQuery** para clonar el segmento `<div id=actividades>` y le hice unos cambios necesarios para su correcto funcionamiento futuro.

1) **Al clonar** el bloque se debe borrar / modificar el ID de la fuente para que no se repita ya que ese valor es unico en los elementos HTML.

2) **Oculte en los clones** el boton de agregar para que sea solamente el bloque original el encargado de crear uno nuevo.

3) Ahora **Se incluye un boton para borrar la fila clonada** solamente aparece en las nuevas filas clonadas.

4) En el boton hay un numerador de fila para indicar la linea creada la cual es opcional y puede ocultarse o quitarse del codigo, su idea es ilustrar que borra la fila seleccionada.

Aqui esta el nuevo codigo (**CON BOTON ELIMINAR)**:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/fontawesome/css/all.css">
        <script src="CSS/fontawesome/js/all.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Acuerdos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" >

            <fieldset>
                <form id="archivo">
                        <legend> Captura de Acuerdo </legend>
                        <div class="alert alert-info" style="width: 100%;">
                            <strong>Los campos obligatorios estan marcados con * </strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                <input  id="time" name="time" class="form-control" type="number" lang="en"   value=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- actividades -->
                        <div class="row" id="actividades">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="inputState" id="nombre"><strong>* </strong>A. Global:</label>
                                <select id="ActvG" class="form-control" name="ActvG" onchange=""  >
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="inputState" id="nombre">A. General:</label>
                                <select id="ActvP" class="form-control" name="ActvP" onchange="" >
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="inputState" id="nombre">A. Particular:</label>
                                <select id="SubAct" class="form-control" name="SubAct" onchange="">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="inputState" id="nombre">SubActividad:</label>
                                <select id="SubbAct" class="form-control" name="SubbAct" >
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-plus" style="font-size: 0.6rem;line-height: 0.9;" onclick="">+</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-minus" style="font-size: 0.6rem;line-height: 0.9; display: none;" onclick="">-</button>
                                <span class="fila"></span>
                            </div>
                      </div> <!-- fin # actividades -->

                    <div id="nuevaactividad">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="JS/acciones.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/Alta_Archivo.js"></script>

    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        // contador de lineas
        var linea = 0;
        // agregar una nueva lista
        $(".btn-plus").on("click",  function() {
            $("#actividades").clone().appendTo("#nuevaactividad");
            // ocultar signo de mas a items a los clonados
            var i = $( ".btn-plus" ).length-1;
            document.getElementsByClassName("btn-plus")[i].setAttribute("style", "display: none;"); 
            // mostra signo menos en filas clonadas
            document.getElementsByClassName("btn-minus")[i].setAttribute("style", "display: block; line-height: 10px !important;");
            linea++;
            document.getElementsByClassName("fila")[i].innerHTML=linea;
            // eliminar el id de los clonados (se dejan el original)
            $("[id='ActvG']:eq("+ i + ")").attr("id","")
            $("[id='ActvP']:eq("+ i + ")").attr("id","")
            $("[id='SubAct']:eq("+ i + ")").attr("id","")
            $("[id='SubbAct']:eq("+ i + ")").attr("id","")
            // los names se pueden llamar para tomar su valor usando un arreglo
        });

        // quitar una lista (se escucha un elemento creado dinamicamente)
        $("#nuevaactividad").on("click",".btn-minus" ,function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();

        });

    </script>

</html>
```

**PARA PROBAR EL CODIGO:**

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/fontawesome/css/all.css">
        <script src="CSS/fontawesome/js/all.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Acuerdos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" >
            
            <fieldset>
                <form id="archivo">
                        <legend> Captura de Acuerdo </legend>
                        <div class="alert alert-info" style="width: 100%;">
                            <strong>Los campos obligatorios estan marcados con * </strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                <input  id="time" name="time" class="form-control" type="number" lang="en"   value=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- actividades -->
                        <div class="row" id="actividades">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="inputState" id="nombre"><strong>* </strong>A. Global:</label>
                                <select id="ActvG" class="form-control" name="ActvG" onchange=""  >
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="inputState" id="nombre">A. General:</label>
                                <select id="ActvP" class="form-control" name="ActvP" onchange="" >
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="inputState" id="nombre">A. Particular:</label>
                                <select id="SubAct" class="form-control" name="SubAct" onchange="">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="inputState" id="nombre">SubActividad:</label>
                                <select id="SubbAct" class="form-control" name="SubbAct" >
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-plus" style="font-size: 0.6rem;line-height: 0.9;" onclick="">+</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-minus" style="font-size: 0.6rem;line-height: 0.9; display: none;" onclick="">-</button>
                                <span class="fila"></span>
                            </div>
                      </div> <!-- fin # actividades -->

                    <div id="nuevaactividad">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="JS/acciones.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/Alta_Archivo.js"></script>

    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        // contador de lineas
        var linea = 0;
        // agregar una nueva lista
        $(".btn-plus").on("click",  function() {
            $("#actividades").clone().appendTo("#nuevaactividad");
            // ocultar signo de mas a items a los clonados
            var i = $( ".btn-plus" ).length-1;
            document.getElementsByClassName("btn-plus")[i].setAttribute("style", "display: none;"); 
            // mostra signo menos en filas clonadas
            document.getElementsByClassName("btn-minus")[i].setAttribute("style", "display: block; line-height: 10px !important;");
            linea++;
            document.getElementsByClassName("fila")[i].innerHTML=linea;
            // eliminar el id de los clonados (se dejan el original)
            $("[id='ActvG']:eq("+ i + ")").attr("id","")
            $("[id='ActvP']:eq("+ i + ")").attr("id","")
            $("[id='SubAct']:eq("+ i + ")").attr("id","")
            $("[id='SubbAct']:eq("+ i + ")").attr("id","")
            // los names se pueden llamar para tomar su valor usando un arreglo
        });

        // quitar una lista (se escucha un elemento creado dinamicamente)
        $("#nuevaactividad").on("click",".btn-minus" ,function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();

        });

    </script>

</html>
```

**La salida en pantalla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: woow muchas gracias justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: No te olvides de calificar la respuesta : )

Comment: Muchas gracias, siempre a la orden!

Comment: otra pregunta si por ejemplo se equivocaran y agregaran una de mas como podría hacer para eliminar la ultima creada

Comment: hay que crear un boton para eliminar, el cual debe estar en cada clone creado, dame un momento y te paso el codigo con ese boton

Comment: muchas gracias :)

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con los cambios para eliminar las filas,  coloque tambien un numerador para indicar cual fila ha sido borrada

Comment: muchas gracias esta perfecto :)

Comment: hola espero y le llegue el comentario segui con este codigo que creo pero tengo un problema solo elimina el id del primer clonado y de los siguientes les deje el mismo id del original. como se podria corregir esto ya intente pero no lo he logrado al parecer solo lo llega a hacer la primera vez